# callback to Google Play from Facebook post made my Android app

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I would like to ask for a little bit of help. I am developing a native Android application which is able to post an image using a so called  'Android Share Extension'. This works perfectly, and the image is appearing in the user's timeline.

I was expecting the name of my application to appear as well and a redirect option to Google Play when any user (which does not have the app installed) clicks the post.

I think i should use an app link, but cannot find out how to implement this. Currently, I am posting the picture like this:

```
Uri myImageContentUri = .... 
String myAppId = "my app id";
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myImageContentUri);
shareIntent.putExtra("com.facebook.platform.extra.APPLICATION_ID", myAppId);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"), myRequestId);
```

What do I have to do to link back to Google Play (or my app if it's already installed)?

Comment: Have you checked out the documentation about Sharing on Android yet? It looks like it covers your use-case https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: Hi, yes this was the first place I checked ;) I created a applink, but I am not able to link that app link to the image i am using through the native share dialog. I am not using the facebook sdk in my project, just the native share dialog. Posting to facebook is succesful, but i am not able to link back to google play/ my app.